# Не работает команда для бана

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

if вполне работает, типо если написать просто **>ban** без пинга участника которого нужно забанить всё прекрасно будет писать, что нужно упоминать пользователя которого я хочу забанить, но когда я упоминаню пользователя (>ban @пользователь) ничего не происходит, консоль молчит, вот сам код бана:

```py
#Команда для бана участника сервера
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Произошла ошибка', description='Правильное использования команды:\n**>ban @пользователь**',color=0xe74c3c))
        return
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = 0xEC2C2D,
    title="Ban",
    description=f"Ban user { member.mention }"
    )
    embed.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    embed.set_author( name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar_url )
    await member.ban()
    await ctx.send( embed = embed)
```

Comment: Есть ли у вас загруженный ивент `on_command_error`

Comment: Да, есть ивент on_command_error

Comment: Уберите его, перезапустите бота, запустите команду и укажите ошибку здесь, в комментариях